# the modifying can not be visible in the same transaction in spring data jpa,why i got null after modifying in the same transaction?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa

show code first,here is my code,as below:

```
   public void saveTestTx() {
        Lock lock = new Lock();
        lock.setName("ABCDEFG");
        lock.setDeviceId("22dfgdfgdftrtg");
        lock.setCreateTime((new Date()));
        Lock lock1 = lockDao.saveAndFlush(lock);
        System.out.println("lock1 = " + lock1);
        Lock lock2 = lockDao.findByDeviceId(lock.getDeviceId());
        System.out.println("lock2 = " + lock2);  // got null here
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0zbq.png)(here is the screenshot)

i'm sure that the method 'saveTestTx()' is a completely transaction ,  because if i called print(22/0) ,it can be rolled back.  i mean that the codes from line 192 to line 199 are in the a same transaction . from my java development experience, i think the lock2 is the result of lock1, i know that before printing the  lock2,the transaction have not commited yet,but they are in a same transaction,the modifying in the  same transaction would be visible  ,so before comitting transaction,it could be selected from after called "saveAndFlush()" method, and the insert statement is printed at console,but in fact, **why lock2 is printed null?**

my transaction configration is as below:

```
@Configuration
public class TxConfig {
    @Bean("txSource")
    public TransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSource() {
        NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource source = new NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource();
        RuleBasedTransactionAttribute readOnlyTx = new RuleBasedTransactionAttribute();
        readOnlyTx.setReadOnly(true);
        readOnlyTx.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        RuleBasedTransactionAttribute requiredTx = new RuleBasedTransactionAttribute(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,
                Collections.singletonList(new RollbackRuleAttribute(Exception.class)));
        int isolationLevel = requiredTx.getIsolationLevel();
        // requiredTx.setTimeout(90);
        Map<String, TransactionAttribute> txMap = new HashMap<>();
        txMap.put("init*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("add*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("save*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("insert*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("create*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("persist*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("update*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("modify*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("merge*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("bind*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("delete*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("del*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("drop*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("remove*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("reset*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("cancel*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("login*", requiredTx);
        txMap.put("*", readOnlyTx);
        source.setNameMap(txMap);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    public AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor pointcutAdvisor(TransactionInterceptor txInterceptor) {
        AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor pointcutAdvisor = new AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor();
        pointcutAdvisor.setAdvice(txInterceptor);
//    pointcutAdvisor.setExpression("execution (* com.hl..service..*.*(..))");
        pointcutAdvisor.setExpression("execution (* com..service..*.*(..)) || execution (* com..dao..*.*(..))");
        return pointcutAdvisor;
    }

    @Bean("txInterceptor")
    TransactionInterceptor getTransactionInterceptor(PlatformTransactionManager tx) {
        return new TransactionInterceptor(tx, transactionAttributeSource());
    }

}
```

my entity code is as below:

```
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "police_lock")
@SQLDelete(sql = "update lock set is_deleted = 1 where id = ?")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = 0")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class Lock extends LongBaseEntity {
    public static interface AddGroup {};
    public static interface UpdateGroup {};

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Lock() {
        super();
    }

    public Lock(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Lock(boolean isInit) {
        super(isInit);
    }
    @NotBlank(groups = {AddGroup.class,UpdateGroup.class})
    private String deviceId;

    @NotBlank(groups = {AddGroup.class,UpdateGroup.class})
    private String name;
}
```

my table is as below:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for police_lock
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `police_lock`;
CREATE TABLE `police_lock` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL COMMENT 'device_id',
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'name',
  `create_time` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'create_time',
 `is_deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0' COMMENT 'is_deleted',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `device_id` (`device_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=96 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='lock';
```

the method findByDeviceId() is a spring data jpa interface method,just defining a method is enough.it's feature of spring data jpa, after called saveAndFlush() method,it send a sql like this:

```
Hibernate: insert into police_lock (create_time, is_deleted, device_id, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and after the method excuted,the transaction was commited and the database generated the new record. of course it's not generated before the method was excuted.but my question is that:**thouth it's not commited,the modifying shoud be saw by following codes in the same transaction be it was not commited. but mine was not.i don't know why.**. Am i missing something here?

my code is under spring boot,spring data jpa,mysql.

Comment: What's the code of the entity? What's the definition of the underlying table? What's the code of findByDeviceId? What are the SQL statements being executed? What do you see in the database after this method is executed?

Comment: Something's fishy: your table doesn't have any `is_deleted` column, yet the SQL statement inserts a value in it. Have you checked that this value is 0? What is the SQL generated by the findByDeviceId() execution?

Comment: thank's for your reply very much, of couse my table has such a column 'is_deleted', and i'm sure it's 0，because i set it 0 as a default value.  to paste code here,i deleted some not key columns, now i updated to  add it now. not only this table,but also all of my tables have the same question,  and no exceptions are thrown,i guess that there  may be something key point or configration i missed?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it now, there is something wrong with my transaction configration,i modified it like as below:

```
@Configuration
public class TxConfig2 {
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean(name = "txAdvice")
    public TransactionInterceptor getAdvisor() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("transactionManager = " + transactionManager);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("init*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("add*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("insert*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("create*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("persist*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("update*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("modify*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("merge*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("bind*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("del*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("drop*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("remove*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("reset*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("cancel*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("login*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("save*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("update*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("delete*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception");
        properties.setProperty("*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception,readOnly");
        TransactionInterceptor tsi = new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, properties);
        return tsi;
    }
    @Bean
    public BeanNameAutoProxyCreator txProxy() {
        BeanNameAutoProxyCreator creator = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
        creator.setInterceptorNames("txAdvice");
        creator.setBeanNames("*Service","*Dao");
        creator.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return creator;
    }
}
```

then it works fine!!!